# How to make text copy in PDF previewers ignore lineno line numbers?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, viewers, line-numbering, copy-paste

I'm using lineno for a document.  I have it configured to put line numbers in the margins of the document.  I generate PDF using pdflatex.  Here's the problem: when people copy a region of text in a PDF previewer (Acrobat, or Mac OS X's Preview), the line numbers are included in the text that's copied.  This leads to confusing text when they paste it into another document or application.

Is there a way to make it so that the line numbers are *ignored* when someone copies text from within a PDF previewer?  I would like just the main text to be copied, not the line numbers.

Comment: This may depend on how you are generating the document, so it is  best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will also help us to test that the solution actually works in your case.

Comment: Related Question: [How to make listings code indentation remain unchanged when copied from pdf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19949/how-to-make-listings-code-indentation-remain-unchanged-when-copied-from-pdf)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using a method similar to that proposed in [How to make listings code correct copyable from PDF and with hyperlink](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30284/how-to-make-listings-code-correct-copyable-from-pdf-and-with-hyperlink/30310#30310), the following works (at least in Adobe Reader).

The [`accsupp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) provides accessibility support for PDFs. By using the `\BeginAccSupp` and `\EndAccSupp` group, the line numbers can be typeset in the PDF, but actually replaced by an empty space `{}`. This is done by supplying the option `ActualText={}`. As such, a simple redefinition of the `linenumber` counter (the basic/standard counter providing the line numbers for [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno)) printing mechanism `\thelinenumber` does the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno
\usepackage{accsupp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\renewcommand{\thelinenumber}{% Line number printing mechanism
  \BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}\arabic{linenumber}\EndAccSupp{}%
}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers% Turn line numbering on

\lipsum[1-5]% Dummy text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, I didn't know about the `ActualText` feature in PDF until now. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this answer (complete with full working example, no less!).  I didn't know `accsupp` existed.  I tried it, and indeed it works, but apparently _only_ in Acrobat; on Mac OS X 10.6, using Preview or a 3rd-party application like Skim, the full text (including line numbers) is still copied.  Do you (or anyone else) have any thoughts about how to make it work for other PDF readers too?  (In any case, thank you again for solving it for Acrobat; that's miles better than not having any solution.)

Comment: @mhucka: I work with Acrobat Reader 99.9% of the time. Therefore, I don't know about other alternatives. The [`accsupp` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/accsupp.pdf) also suggests `ActualText` while referencing (only) Adobe Reader.

Comment: OK, no problem; I'm happy with having at least this much of a solution.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Werner What PDF viewer do you use? Your approach only seems viable for some viewers; it doesn't work in Mac OS X preview, for intance.

Comment: @Jubobs: See the comments above. I mainly use Adobe Reader. I know that many PDF-related features are mostly supported by Adobe, but not by other PDF viewers. The same goes for security features.

Comment: @Werner Yes. I only got suspicious when I realised it wasn' working in Preview. I just tested it in Adobe Reader and it works as advertised. That's also good enough for me, because most of my readers use that viewer.

Comment: What's the potential downside of this?  If there isn't any downside, shouldn't `lineno` do this by default?

Comment: @Ryo: It may be viewer-specific. So, if you're not using Adobe-related PDF viewers, selections may include the line numbers even if accessibility options are used.

Comment: @Werner Understood. But, my question is actually whether there is any potential harm in other PDF viewers when the method is used.  If there is no harm, I'll always use this method when using `lineno`. (Then, if you always write the extra lines in the preamble, you wish it were the default.)

Comment: @Ryo: Harm as in make it not viewable in non-Adobe PDF readers? I doubt that will be the case, but can't say for sure.