# What can cause generated PDF document whose text are not correctly copyable?

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, drm

I was wondering why some PDF documents compiled from some LaTeX code does not make its text correctly copyable, i.e. what you can get is nonsense text? For example, [this pdf document](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~yarowsky/syllabus.415.pdf) (I don't have the LaTeX code for it).

Comment: Looks like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-pdf-with-un-copyable-text to me

Comment: @Joseph -- your link covers the same topic, but from a different angle, namely how can one make this happen.  the present question is "why does it happen?"

Comment: This sort of nonsense text being copied from PDFs was very common with some old versions of Ghostscript when bitmap fonts were involved. Your example PDF is far from being the worst I've seen.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The PDF specification allows for this - displaying something different from what is retrievable. The [`randtext` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/randtext) is perhaps a prime example of this. It provides `\randomize{<text>}` which (from the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/randtext/randtext-doc.pdf))

> ...typesets a box that looks, on paper, like `<text>`, but whose
>   letters have in fact been placed in random order so that they are not
>   copiable from the file directly.

Another example of this provided by the [`accsupp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) which allows one to specify an alternative text to be extracted than displayed using a grouping:

```
\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={<copy>}}<typeset>\EndAccSupp{}
```

For an example of this, see [How to make text copy in PDF previewers ignore lineno line numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30783/5764)

The motivation for this is most certainly security, as is motivated from the `randtext` documentation:

> The function of this odd macro is to obfuscate e-mail addresses, say
>   on a PDF document put online, so that the human reader sees the
>   address as expected, but e-mail address harvesters and spambots cannot
>   determine the address.

Comment: My test document created with `\randomize` from the randtext package does not seem to randomize anything for me. I can happily copy and paste with evince and also `pdftotext` returns all the typeset text.

Comment: @FrederickNord: PDF security, as it seems from numerous other comments I've read, is heavily reliant on the PDF viewer.

Comment: Hm @Werner. I don't know much about PDF, but rumour has it, that you can remove or replace the (easily) machine readable text but still have something that renders text nicely. So a human (or OCR) could indeed read the text while pdftotext could not. Do you happen to know anything about that?

Comment: @FrederickNord: For an entire text, or merely snippets? See, for example, [How to redefine `@` and `.` to obfuscate email addresses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42588/5764) and/or [Obfuscation of `@` and `.` in e-mail addresses](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95123/5764) for email-specific obfuscation.

Comment: I mean for an entire text. Pretty much like [here](http://spivey.oriel.ox.ac.uk/corner/Obfuscated_PDF) but in a more pdfLaTeX way.

Comment: @FrederickNord: Haven't seen anything like that before... and what I've seen, is awesome. It seems like a one-time background fiddling with the font encoding, so it's not required with every run.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7524/discussion-between-frederick-nord-and-werner)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps, more useful would be asking what to do to avoid such troubles. If so, then awswer is to load `cmap` package. It is absolute must if text contains Cyrillic letters. However, to the best of my knowledge, `cmap` is not required if source text is in UTF8 encoding.