# How to redefine @ and . to obfuscate email addresses?

Tags: macros, catcodes

I am writing a small package containing macros I intend to use regularly. Among those macros, I have `\mailto` with the following definition:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \def\mailto#1{%
    \href{mailto:#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}%
  }%
}{%
  \def\maitlo#1{%
    \url{#1}%
  }%
}
```

What I want to do is redefine `@` and `.` to active characters, so that `xxx@yyy.zzz` is turned into `xxx<at>yyy<dot>zzz`. I've tried the following:

```
\def\mailto#1{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`@=13
    \catcode`.=13
    \def@{$\langle$at$\rangle$}
    \def.{$\langle$dot$\rangle$}
    \url{#1}
  \endgroup
}
```

But I get a:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\mailto ...e `@=\active \catcode `.=\active \def@ 
                                                  {$\langle $at$\rangle $} \...
l.XXX \mailto{xxx@yyy.zzz}
```

Why?

Comment: An off-topic but related question: does this alteration actually prevent spam?  You *give away* your email address in hundreds of ways all the time, and it's passed to marketers of questionable morality without the possibility of your doing anything about it.  I have 500 messages in my spam folder and my email address isn't written in *any* form on my website.

Comment: I really don't know. That question arose because I learn by doing. Unfortunately, TeX's documentation isn't very programmer-orientated. I wish there were an MSDN-like documentation system somewhere on the web.

Comment: On a related note about email obfuscation and security, see [What can cause generated PDF document whose text are not correctly copyable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41688/5764)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. Category codes are fixed when TeX reads an argument, and so reading anything with altered codes is tricky. That applies both to the use of `\def.` inside `\def\mailto` and the way you have grabbed the argument of `\mailto` before you alter category codes. That might lead you to something like

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`\@=\active
  \catcode`\.=\active
  \gdef\mailto{%
    \begingroup
      \catcode`\@=\active
      \catcode`\.=\active
      \gdef@{$\langle$at$\rangle$}%
      \gdef.{$\langle$dot$\rangle$}%
      \mailtoaux
  }
  \gdef\mailtoaux#1{%
    \endgroup
    #1%
  }
\endgroup
```

Notice that I've split the group used for `\mailto`, so that it starts before I grab the argument, and ends after I've grabbed it.

However, this won't work for a URL as the `url` package does a verbatim read here. In any case, I would avoid active characters (not really needed), and instead to a search-and-replace. I would do this with something like

```
\newcommand*{\mynil}{\mynil}
\newcommand*{\mailto}[1]{%
  \mailtoauxi#1@\mynil@\stop
}
\def\mailtoauxi#1@#2@#3\stop{%
  \ifx\mynil#2%
    \ERROR
  \else
    \mailtoauxii#1<at>#2.\mynil.\stop
  \fi
}
\makeatletter
\def\mailtoauxii#1.#2.#3\stop{%
  \ifx\mynil#2%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
    {\url{#1}}%
    {\mailtoauxii#1<dot>#2.#3\stop}%
}
\makeatother
```

As I said, `\url` deliberately works to print verbatim, so to get the math mode substitution you want will be a little more work!

Comment: I could box and split the URL into x components depending on the address.