# disabling active email link in IEEEtran

Tags: ieeetran

I have the following line in the authors affiliations section in an IEEEtran-class-based paper:

```
Email: \{author1,author2\}@example.com
```

When the paper is compiled, the above becomes the following active link

> "mailto:author2}@example.com".

How do I prevent it from happening? I just want the above email link to be plain text and read as `{author1,author2}@example.com`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a compilable example?

Comment: Note that some PDF viewers have some heuristics for detecting URIs in them, like Web links or email addresses and you can't disable it. If you don't load `hyperref` there will be no real link in the PDF document, which is how much you can get, because anybody opening the PDF with a previewer having those heuristics will see a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be an attribute of the PDF specification *and* viewer, since you're not even including [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). That is, when you have something of the form `<possibly something>@<something>.<something>`, it's interpreted as an email (without the `@`, perhaps a website). An effective way I've been able to remove this automated interpretation is to create a space at some inconspicuous location within the string-in-question. Somewhat similar to writing `{author1,author2}@example .com`. For example, using

```
Email: \{homer, lisa\}@thesimpsons\hspace{0.125em}.com}% Remove hyperlink from email
```

If you try this yourself, you'll note that using a space of only `0.12em` doesn't remove the hyperlink when viewed in Adobe Reader, suggesting that TeX is not involved here.

Another option would be to insert some non-link-related content. Below I've made `\emaildot` which is a scaled-down version of `\textbullet`, simulating a `.`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{ieeetran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\emaildot}{\makebox[0.2em]{\scalebox{.23}{\textbullet}}}
\title{A title}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\
    Computer Engineering\\
    Georgia Institute of Technology\\
    Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
    Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
  \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Homer Simpson}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
    Springfield, USA\\
    Email: \{homer, lisa\}@thesimpsons\emaildot com}% Remove hyperlink from email
  \and
    \IEEEauthorblockN{James Kirk\\
    and Montgomery Scott}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
    San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
    Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
    Fax: (888) 555--1212}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The contact information above, as an example, was taken from the [`IEEEtran` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf).

---

The above method is similar to the suggestion in [Obfuscation of `@` and `.` in e-mail addresses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95123/5764). Somewhat different, but similar.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this has nothing to do with IEEETran template. If you use Acrobat/Acroreader, just turn the `edit-> preferences...-> general-> create links from url` option off. If you are using sumartraPDF, nothing can be done at the moment.