# Automating the appearance of email addresses as images

Tags: pdftex, urls, privacy

Publishing pdf manuscripts on the web with emails embedded in the file results in spam.

More generally, I am looking for a way to *automate* the conversion of a string to an image.

It's quite easy to solve this old problem using [`\includegraphics` an image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95153/9549) (more [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150793/9549)). The trouble is that you need a distinct file and typesetting run, and you end up with unnecessary image files that you cannot delete carelessly lest you also delete non-generated images.

Can you think of a way to do this on the fly? It's understood that people will have to type the email addresses if they need to message you, but that's the point.

**More briefly/concretely**...

With what can one replace `#1`

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\showasimage[1]{#1}
\begin{document}
\showasimage{joe@foo.bar}
\end{document}
```

such that `#1` appears as an image?

**Edit**

It would be really nice if the pdf file remains vectorial.

Comment: I think it might be better to do something like `joe <at> foo <dot> bar` so that people using screen reading software can still email you. If it is an image, there is not much you can do if you can't see it. (Or does PDF have a way to insert this as alternate text in the same way html does? Then you could provide this for screen readers and the image for everyone else.) That said: http://ctan.org/pkg/randtext will do what you want.

Comment: Actually, `randtext` doesn't work here. I get no errors, the output is fine but copy-and-paste is not scrambled at all.

Comment: Be careful that for some viewers/printers the text of the image (in this case the email) can look/print very different from the the rest of the text, even if the resolution of the image is high.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150375/crawler-resistance-email-address/150733#150733.  While it doesn't use an image approach, it makes it so the copy/paste produces a junk email address.

Comment: For the partiucular objective of hiding the email text, there is other approach http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95123/obfuscation-of-and-in-e-mail-addresses. (But the question is good in general).

Comment: I think that kind of security can be broken. How ? Analyze the pdf, extract all the pictures, and then analyze this images with an OCR program. Not feasible by anybody but feasible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following solution does not (anymore) use ImageMagick's `convert` command as this would always create raster images, which will stand out from the text. Instead, it uses Ghostscript to vectorise the letters so that they appear like normal text but are in fact an uncopyable image. Note that you also have to run `pdflatex` with the `--shell-escape` switch enabled, so that the commands from `\write18` will indeed be sent to the shell.

The image will be cropped so that it is placed on the base line (with descenders taken into account), and the font will match the one from the context. The temporary files (using a counter to allow more than one image on the same page) will be deleted at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcount\@emailcount
\newcommand\showasimage[1]{%
  \global\advance\@emailcount 1
  \edef\x{email-\the\@emailcount}%
  \immediate\write18{echo '\unexpanded{\\font\\1=}\fontname\font' > \x.tex}%
  \immediate\write18{echo '\unexpanded{\\1#1\\nopagenumbers\\bye}' >> \x.tex}%
  \immediate\write18{pdftex \x.tex}%
  %\immediate\write18{convert -units PixelsPerInch -density 300 -trim \x.pdf \x.png}% raster
  \immediate\write18{gs -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=epswrite -dQUIET -o \x.eps \x.pdf}% vector
  \immediate\write18{epstopdf --hires \x.eps}%
  \settodepth{\@tempdima}{#1}%
  \raisebox{-\the\@tempdima}{\includegraphics{\x.pdf}}%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \loop
    \immediate\write18{rm email-\the\@emailcount.*}%
    \advance\@emailcount-1
    \ifnum\@emailcount>0\repeat
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Email \showasimage{oe@foo.bar} not copyable

\textit{match font and depth: \showasimage{joe@foo.bar}} 

\end{document}
```

which yields (with the first line selected):

[image: emails as images]

Comment: Slightly more elaborate...  Is this the 'microtype' solution?

Comment: Nice - I am thinking that the use of `convert` can be avoided with this idea. The `standalone` package can make trimmed output.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen Indeed! I have a hunch that a combination of standalone and either bashful or Robert's write18 (what is that!?) would make it possible to use a vector image. The result would then be indistinguishable from normal text inclusion (and the pdf file will likely be much smaller).

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen -- `standalone` uses ImageMagick by default as its conversion program.  (Though it can be modified to use something else like Ghostscript.)

Comment: @Calaf It would indeed be better to create vector images from the text, but I don't know of a command line tool that can do that (Adobe Illustrator can, but that's of course not an option). Maybe Ghostscript?

Comment: @jon 'micrographics', rather ...

Comment: Ha, micrographics indeed!

Answer (score 9):

This works for me, but I don't know about your OS, so I'm not sure if it will work for you.  Note that the command `convert` is part of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).  Compile with `-shell-escape` enabled.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bashful,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\bash
echo "jon@jon.com" | convert label:@- email.png
\END
\includegraphics{email.png}

\end{document}
```

That won't work in a `\newcommand`, however.  But this seems to work (still on `bash`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\showasimage}[2]{%
\immediate\write18{echo "#1" | convert label:@- #2.png}%
\includegraphics{#2.png}%
}

\begin{document}

\showasimage{jon2@jon2.com}{email2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `label:@-` mean? `man convert` tells me that all options start with a `-`.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen -- It's to get a label from standard input; see [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label), at the end of the section.

Comment: Ok - I my mistake. Just simpler to write: `convert label:#1 #2.png`

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen -- Sure.  Same number of chars either way :).  In TeX, at least.  I'm used to thinking of `convert` mainly in a non-TeX usage...

Comment: How nice to discover the bashful package! I'm sure it will come in handy quite often.