# Any way to change a character to an image?

Tags: graphics

Sometimes, it is needed to change a character to an image: for example, change *@* in an email address to an image. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: If you change it to a vectorized image using something like ['Standalone' TikZ pictures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32127/5764) than you'll still end up with selectable text. But perhaps the following is more in-line with what you're after: [Automating the appearance of email addresses as images](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160356/5764), or [Obfuscation of `@` and `.` in e-mail addresses](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95123/5764).

Comment: @Werner thank you very much for the reply: now i use the first solution you recommend.

Comment: Also this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150375/crawler-resistance-email-address