# obfuscate latex->pdf document

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, drm

Is there any package that can easily allow you to obfuscate a Latex->PDF generated document such that copy-paste is not longer possible and produces random letters for instance.

And if yes, is it possible to control which letters get modified?

Mailin

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150375/crawler-resistance-email-address

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.