# Rendering text as image to protect e-mail address

Tags: tex-core

I want to protect my e-mail address against spammers by including it as image instead of a (parsable) text. Normally I would have to create the image (with text) by myself and include this as figure. Is there a way of automatizing this (e.g. a package)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150375/crawler-resistance-email-address, for example, and other related questions.

Comment: Also, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-pdf-with-un-copyable-text.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that, I already saw these posts. I am looking for a picture only solution which does not involve a third application as the domain should be obfuscated as well..

Comment: There is also the [`randtext` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/randtext).

Comment: Using an image excludes visually impaired people. Therefore you also would need an audio file at least. And the spammers just continue with OCR ...

Comment: Is this really a problem?  My email address has been in a href="mailto: on my web site for years.  About the only spam I get these days (or at least the only ones who get through the spam blockers) are idiots who think I should be selling life insurance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this with `pdflatex --shell-escape`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\hideemail#1#2{%
\IfFileExists{#1.png}{}%
{\immediate\write18{%
echo '\detokenize{\setbox0\hbox{\strut #2}\hoffset-1in\voffset-1in\pdfpageheight\baselineskip
\pdfpagewidth\wd0\shipout\box0\bye'|pdftex;convert -density 600 texput.pdf #1.png}}}%
\box0{#2}%
\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=\wd0]{#1.png}}}%

\begin{document}

some text with \hideemail{myemail}{david@example.com} an address

\end{document}
```

The exact command sequence written to the `\write18` line depending on the utilities and operating system you have available. It uses plain pdftex to write a pdf just containing the address, then imagemagic convert to make a png.

the result is

[image]

However this gives absolutely no security to the email address, for example if I load the pdf (or even the png image of the pdf as uploaded to this site)
into google docs it OCRs it automatically producing

```
 some text with david@example.com an address
```

as plain text.

If google can OCR that automatically on file upload, so can whoever you are trying to hide this from.