# How to protect a word from finding by google search machines

Tags: graphics

With Google it's possible to search for documents uploaded on webpages which contain a specific text inside the text.

```
\begin{titlepage}
A summary\\
\vspace*{3cm}\\
© Max Mustermann\\ % I used the copyright-symbol as you can see
3. May 2015\\
\end{titlepage}
```

I have done a screenshot and inputed as a picture with `\includegraphics[height=1.26em]{MaxMustermann.png}` 
to protect the document before Google search entries.

When I zoom in the PDF I can see that this is a picture.

Is there another way (e.g. with a package or to use a overlaying blank box) to protect a specific text before finding with Google and prohibit also before Searching the PDF-Document the text "Mustermann"?

In comparision this question is not only about prohibiting searching it's also about prohibiting from finding from google.

Should I use one of the packages described in the following link?

[Rendering text as image to protect e-mail address](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238907/rendering-text-as-image-to-protect-e-mail-address)

Comment: Use \https:  where people have to pay to see it.  That's how the IEEE does it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That's not inherently dependent on https. You can have https which is open and public. You can have pay-to-see which is not https (although that would be silly in many cases but silliness has never stopped people's creativity in the past).

Comment: It doesn't work with every PDF viewer, and as such, I'm unsure if it will work with Google, but you could try the `accsupp` package as used here: [Is it possible to prevent some part of text (headers, footers) from selection?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49505)

Answer (score 2):

As Paul suggests, the `accsupp` package can help here, which I show as one method.  I also include a 2nd method, of `\rlap`ing white text in the middle of the protected word.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,accsupp}
\begin{document}
\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={Can't search me}}%
Max Mustermann
\EndAccSupp{}%

Max Mus\rlap{\textcolor{white}{xyz}}termann
\end{document}
```

The image is

[image]

But a copy/paste of the PDF file results in

```
Can't search me
Max Mustxeyrzmann
```