# Can anything be done to add superscript letters to words, without messing up PDF Search functionality?

Tags: superscripts, search

I am creating a PDF Bible for personal use; it includes both footnotes (which are superscripted numbers appended to the end of certain words), and margin cross-references (which are superscripted letters prepended to the front of certain words).

The cross-references are nothing more than this command, applied to words in the text:

command: `\newcommand{\mref}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textit{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}}`.

application:  `does not annul a \mref{d}covenant previously \mref{e}ratified by God`

**Here's the Problem:** *PDF Search does find any word with a cross-ref in front of it!*

I'm using the PDF in GoodNotes iOS app - which has a wonderful search capability, both for the text, and any handwritten notes.

The search function in GoodNotes does not find word-matches for words that are preceded by a superscripted letter.  There's probably no fix for this ... but asking anyway ... Is there some optional method of separating the word from a superscript in such a way that a PDF document recognizes the word apart from the reference letter besides a physical space?  Or to space, and back up the render some amount to make it look like the reference letter is next to the word ?

Or any other suggestions for this issue ?

Comment: you could try simply adjusting the macro so that it has eg `\nobreak\hspace{0pt}` after the superscript before the word, or you can probably use pdf tagging to separate the word and the annotation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I doubt that \hspace{0pt} would change something, it wouldn't add something to the pdf so why should it matter. You probably would need a real space char. (I can't test that, adobe has no problems to find convenant in mwe.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ... experimenting with your ideas.  The /nospace doesnt work (not for the goodnotes app).  So far, `\newcommand{\mref}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textit{\textcolor{blue}{#1 \hspace{-2.0pt}}}}}` works for most cases (note: actual space between #1 and \hspace ) ... but failed for a few instances ... like a "b" in front of "without" ... I am trying to find the minimal negative \hspace value that works for everything ... My text size is \small ... next to try is -1.9pt ... there is such a small visual spacing with -2.0pt that it's not too bad.   BLUF some amount of spacing is required.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer actualtext the word with itself?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It could work but probably not for all viewers. For me adobe finds the actualtext but sumatra doesn't.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ... what do you mean by actual text the word with itself ?

Comment: You can add an actualtext with the accsupp package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ... thanks, interesting.          For now, `\newcommand{\mref}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textit{\textcolor{blue}{#1 \hspace{-2.0pt}}}}}` seems to work for fairly well.  Visually, with size \small{} the space is not too bad.

Comment: You could try `a\pdffakespace b` (assuming that you use pdflatex)

Comment: Regarding the use of `accsupp` package, this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241968/how-to-protect-a-word-from-finding-by-google-search-machines, focuses on protection against google search, but the same logic applies for PDF search, as well.