# TeX - make copy/paste difficult?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, copy-paste, copyright

I have a christmas question for you. I have now tried to copy paste some elements from a document compiled in TeX. Sometimes it looks like this:

> ❆t ❧❛st✱ ❛♥❞ t❛❦✐♥❣ t❤❡ r✐s❦ ❛ ❜❡✐♥❣ t♦♦ ❛❜str❛❝t✱ ■ s❤♦✉❧❞ ♣♦✐♥t ♦✉t
>   t❤❛t ❡✈♦❧✉t✐♦♥❛r2 ❛❧❣♦r✐t❤♠s ❛r❡ ✐♥s♣✐r❡❞ ❜2 ♥❛t✉r❡✬s ❡✈♦❧✉t✐♦♥❛r2
>   ♣r♦❝❡ss✳ ❚❤✐s ✐s ❛ ❣♦♦❞ ♦♣♣♦rt✉♥✐t2 t♦ ❣❛✐♥ s♦♠❡ ✐♥s✐❣❤t ❤♦✇ ❞❡❡♣❧2
>   ❝❛♥ t❤❛t ♠❡t❛♣❤♦r ❤♦❧❞✳ ❙♣❡❝✐❛❧❧2 s✐♥❝❡ ❧✐❢❡ ✐ts❡❧❢ ✐s ❧❡ss ❛
>   ♣❤❡♥♦♠❡♥❛ ♦❢ ♦♣t✐♠✐s✐♥❣ ❢✉♥❝t✐♦♥❛❧✐t2 ❜✉t ♠♦r❡ ♦❢ ❣❡tt✐♥❣ ❣♦♦❞ r❡s✉❧ts
>   ✇✐t❤ ✇❤❛t 2♦✉ ❛❧r❡❛❞2 ❤❛✈❡ ✇❤✐❧❡ ♥♦t ❜❡❝♦♠✐♥❣ t♦♦ s❡♥s✐t✐✈❡ t♦
>   ✐♥t❡r♥❛❧ ❛♥❞ ❡1t❡r♥❛❧ ✈❛r✐❛t✐♦♥✳ ❚❤✐s ❧❛st ❛s♣❡❝t ♠✉st ♥♦t st❛♥❞ ✐♥
>   t❤❡ ✇❛2 ♦❢ ♦❜t❛✐♥✐♥❣ ♣❤❡♥♦t2♣❡s ✇✐t❤ ❜✐♦❧♦❣✐❝❛❧ ✐♥t❡r❡st ❜✉t ✐s
>   r❡❧❡✈❛♥t ♥♦♥❡t❤❡❧❡ss✳

Can someone tell me, how I can do that to make my tex-document more difficult for copy-pasters?

Comment: For starters, consider reading [What can cause generated PDF document whose text are not correctly copyable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41686/5764)

Comment: Welcome! The question title asks to make copy/paste difficult, while in the body, you seem to want to make it easier/more accurate. Which do you want? It would also be helpful to see the TeX code that produced the document that copy/paste result is drawn from. The solution may depend on certain things happening in the document.

Comment: Dear Paul. Thank you. I just use a normal template, but I am going to to send a pdftex-file to some of my clients, which I won't allow to copy and paste from. I can't protect the document by be writing by themselves.

Comment: This is mostly a PDF question.  That is, will copying and pasting from the PDF produce something that can't be recognized by any other software?  (like th and ff)

Comment: Welcome! I guess that you are sure none of your clients depend on accessibility features in PDFs? Not that TeX is great for this - it isn't. But it is certainly possible to make things even harder for people. There really is no way to do what you want in a way which will not simply frustrate the less technically-inclined while constituting a mild irritant for the more technically-savy. The best you can do, probably, is turn it into an image. But (1) decent OCR will easily convert it back to text and (2) it will increase the file size dramatically. Maybe work on the trust thingy?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it looks like a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11307/7883

Comment: What, precisely, is the useful objective of preventing your readers from copy-and-pasting? For those who really want to copy your work for (I suppose) "nefarious purposes", there are text image recognition programs, or even typists.  For others, you're merely providing inconvenience. In early 19th-century England, the Luddites tried something analogous, by smashing looms. They failed.

Comment: I can't find a solution on my problem - could you help me?