# Change symbol drawn in tikz by a character in the pdf text

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, pdf, characters

I was drawing my set of dice, like the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {ifthen}
\usepackage   {tikz}

\tikzset%
{%
  pics/die/.style={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[x=1ex,y=1ex]
      \draw[line width=0.15ex,rounded corners=0.3ex] (-0.75,-0.75) rectangle (0.75,0.75);
      \ifthenelse{#1 > 3}
      {%
        \fill (-0.4, 0.4) circle (0.15); % top left dot
        \fill ( 0.4,-0.4) circle (0.15); % bottom right dot
      }{}% do nothing
      \ifthenelse{#1 > 1}
      {%
        \fill ( 0.4, 0.4) circle (0.15); % top right dot
        \fill (-0.4,-0.4) circle (0.15); % bottom left dot
      }{}
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 6}
      {%
        \fill (-0.4,0) circle (0.15);    % center left dot
        \fill ( 0.4,0) circle (0.15);    % center right dot
      }{}
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 1 \OR #1 = 3 \OR #1 = 5}{\fill (0,0) circle (0.15);}{} % center dot
      \end{scope}
      }}
}

\begin{document}
\huge

\foreach\i in {1,...,6}{\tikz \pic[red] {die={\i}};\,}

Snake Eyes: \tikz\pic {die={1}}; \tikz\pic {die={1}};

Fever Five: \tikz\pic {die={4}}; \tikz\pic {die={1}};
\end{document}
```

[image]

**My question** is whether it would be possible to assign a character to each die so that you could select it as text in the pdf. I want, for example, to select the 'Fever Five: [die 4] [die 1]'  line in the pdf, and copy-paste in another document as 'Fever Five: 4 1'.

I know that there are unicode characters for this purpose, and probably many packages that can do the same, but I want to do it this way (if possible).

Comment: You might be interested in the `accsup` package. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41688/82917

Comment: @campa, it looks promising, but if I write `\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={1}} \tikz \pic {die={1}}; \EndAccSupp{}` I can't select the die in the generated pdf. It works with `\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={1}}2\EndAccSupp{}` though. It probably accepts only text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using a trick?

Write transparent but copiable text behind your dice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{transparent}

\tikzset%
{%
  pics/die/.style={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[x=1ex,y=1ex]
      \draw[line width=0.15ex,rounded corners=0.3ex] (-0.75,-0.75) rectangle (0.75,0.75);
      \ifthenelse{#1 > 3}
      {%
        \fill (-0.4, 0.4) circle (0.15); % top left dot
        \fill ( 0.4,-0.4) circle (0.15); % bottom right dot
      }{}% do nothing
      \ifthenelse{#1 > 1}
      {%
        \fill ( 0.4, 0.4) circle (0.15); % top right dot
        \fill (-0.4,-0.4) circle (0.15); % bottom left dot
      }{}
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 6}
      {%
        \fill (-0.4,0) circle (0.15);    % center left dot
        \fill ( 0.4,0) circle (0.15);    % center right dot
      }{}
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 1 \OR #1 = 3 \OR #1 = 5}{\fill (0,0) circle (0.15);}{} % center dot
      \end{scope}
      }}
}

\newlength{\lungnum}
\newcommand{\dado}[2][black]{\settowidth{\lungnum}{#2}\texttransparent{0}{#2}\hspace{-\lungnum}\tikz{\pic[#1] {die={#2}};}}

\begin{document}
\huge

\foreach\i in {1,...,6}{\dado[red]{\i}\,}

Snake Eyes: \dado{1} \dado{1}

Fever Five: \dado{4} \dado{1}

\end{document}
```

Copy-pasting the resulting pdf:

[image]

You get:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
Snake Eyes: 1 1
Fever Five: 4 1
```

As Juan suggested, it works also using hidden nodes with transparent text (`opacity=0`). In this case, you don't even have to load `transparent` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset%
{%
  pics/die/.style={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[x=1ex,y=1ex]
      \draw[line width=0.15ex,rounded corners=0.3ex] (-0.75,-0.75) rectangle (0.75,0.75);
      \ifthenelse{#1 > 3}
      {%
        \fill (-0.4, 0.4) circle (0.15); % top left dot
        \fill ( 0.4,-0.4) circle (0.15); % bottom right dot
      }{}% do nothing
      \ifthenelse{#1 > 1}
      {%
        \fill ( 0.4, 0.4) circle (0.15); % top right dot
        \fill (-0.4,-0.4) circle (0.15); % bottom left dot
      }{}
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 6}
      {%
        \fill (-0.4,0) circle (0.15);    % center left dot
        \fill ( 0.4,0) circle (0.15);    % center right dot
      }{}
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 1 \OR #1 = 3 \OR #1 = 5}{\fill (0,0) circle (0.15);}{} % center dot
      \end{scope}
      }}
}

\newlength{\lungnum}
\newcommand{\dado}[2][black]{\tikz{\node[opacity=0,inner sep=0cm]{#2};\pic[#1] {die={#2}};}}

\begin{document}
\huge

\foreach\i in {1,...,6}{\dado[red]{\i}\,}

Snake Eyes: \dado{1} \dado{1}

Fever Five: \dado{4} \dado{1}

\end{document}
```

Obviously, you can insert the node with `opacity=0` directly in your `pic` and don't change anything of the rest of your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {ifthen}
\usepackage   {tikz}

\tikzset%
{%
  pics/die/.style={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}[x=1ex,y=1ex]
      \node[opacity=0,inner sep=0cm]{#1};
      \draw[line width=0.15ex,rounded corners=0.3ex] (-0.75,-0.75) rectangle (0.75,0.75);
      \ifthenelse{#1 > 3}
      {%
        \fill (-0.4, 0.4) circle (0.15); % top left dot
        \fill ( 0.4,-0.4) circle (0.15); % bottom right dot
      }{}% do nothing
      \ifthenelse{#1 > 1}
      {%
        \fill ( 0.4, 0.4) circle (0.15); % top right dot
        \fill (-0.4,-0.4) circle (0.15); % bottom left dot
      }{}
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 6}
      {%
        \fill (-0.4,0) circle (0.15);    % center left dot
        \fill ( 0.4,0) circle (0.15);    % center right dot
      }{}
      \ifthenelse{#1 = 1 \OR #1 = 3 \OR #1 = 5}{\fill (0,0) circle (0.15);}{} % center dot
      \end{scope}
      }}
}

\begin{document}
\huge

\foreach\i in {1,...,6}{\tikz \pic[red] {die={\i}};\,}

Snake Eyes: \tikz\pic {die={1}}; \tikz\pic {die={1}};

Fever Five: \tikz\pic {die={4}}; \tikz\pic {die={1}};
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like it!! It's very simple. I'll try to include the transparent numbers in the pics, if possible. Then it won't be necessary to play with the lengths. Thanks!!

Comment: Even better!! :-)

Comment: @JuanCastaño Obviously, you can put the fake node directly in the `pic` and don't change anything of the rest of your code, see my edit (I think you already did it but I added it to the answer for compleness).

Comment: Thanks again!! :D

Comment: @JuanCastaño You're welcome!