# Make hyphenated words in PDF searchable

Tags: pdf, hyphenation, copy-paste

Is there a way to make hyphenated words in a PDF generated by LuaTeX searchable? If the MWE below is converted to a PDF, searching for "lexicon" (in Acrobat X for example) will not find the word since it now contains a hyphen followed by a space character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parbox{2cm}{Break lexicon here.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adobe Reader 10.1.2 on Mac has no problem finding "lexicon". But surprisingly, Preview 5.0.3 can't find it.  BTW, great [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). I just wish more people would provide this.

Comment: You're right, I wrote about Acrobat (which I have installed but didn't try) but tested Preview. So I guess it is really a question of the respective program's search algorithm and not the file format.

Comment: Acrobat X on Windows also has no problem.

Comment: One could use a construction like in question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30783/243 or with the `/E` operator in PDF, see the PDF spec in 10.8.4 Expansion of Abbreviations and Acronyms.

Comment: `skim` 1.3.19 won't find "lexicon".

Comment: Acrobat 9 Pro found it.

Comment: You know it's not unique to LuaTeX, maybe you should modify the question+tags.

Comment: @Dror: Since Skim uses OSX's PDF routines – as does Preview –, that's not surprising.

Comment: @AymanElmasry But there could be a nice LuaTeX solution to overcome that problem.

Comment: I am thinking: Shouldn't this (i.e. making hyphenated words searchable, by whatever means) be standard behavior for pdfTeX or LuaTeX when generating a PDF? Searching PDFs for expressions is such a common thing, really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching the PDF output here is really a function of the viewer. As such, each one takes a different approach to what it will work with. You see that not only with hyphenation but also with other awkward items.

Comment: Indeed : I tried the provided MWE under Linux with Evince, ePDFreader and Okular. Verdict : no, no, yes.

Comment: I disagree. Having the viewer's search function make up for deficiencies in the encoding is not the way to go. The PDF's contents should be encoded so that the difference between a syllable-separating hyphen (inexo-rably) and a word-joining hyphen (anti-imflammatory) at line ends are obvious to the viewer software. As this information is usually present before the document is created, it should not be removed in the process and then re-created heuristically during the search.