# Is there a LaTeX trick to prevent a PDF viewer from copying the line number?

Tags: listings, line-numbering, copy-paste

A PDF output is obtained by compiling the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
        numbers=left,
        numbersep=1em,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\small\tt,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.54,0.13},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    morekeywords={maketitle},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{Sample Document}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello World!
% This is a comment.
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I attempted to copy the code only inside Acrobat Reader. Unfortunately, the line numbers also got copied as shown on the following screen shot.

[image]

The line numbers are useful, but readers want not to copy them.

Is there a LaTeX trick to prevent a PDF viewer from copying the line number?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to make text copy in PDF previewers ignore lineno line numbers?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30783/how-to-make-text-copy-in-pdf-previewers-ignore-lineno-line-numbers)

Comment: @Marco: It is relevant but I cannot find the `listings` counterpart for `\thelinenumber`.

Comment: You should be able to use the `accsupp` package as mentioned in the question @Marco linked to, and use `\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{}` to change how the line numbers are formatted.

Comment: Something like this might be a nice listing addon package. I could add it to my [`lstaddons`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons) bundle.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, what is the "gob­ble" effect that you mention when you describe `lstaddons`, BTW is the feature mentioned in the question implemented in your `lstaddons`. (suggestion: Another extension can be to have to have a filename in the margin, e.g. next to the line numbers)

Comment: @alfC: "to gobble" within (La)TeX means to remove one or more characters/arguments/tokens from the input stream without displaying or processing them. The `gobble` option from `lstaddons` allows to remove whitespaces in front of every line in the verbatim code. This way the verbatim code can be indented.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This solution is *very* similar to that contained in [How to make text copy in PDF previewers ignore lineno line numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30783/5764) `\protect`ing the [`accsupp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) is the only requirement, perhaps due to the nature in which [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) treats *everything*:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{accsupp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp
\renewcommand{\thelstnumber}{% Line number printing mechanism
  \protect\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}\arabic{lstnumber}\protect\EndAccSupp{}%
}
\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
        numbers=left,
        numbersep=1em,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\small\tt,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.54,0.13},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    morekeywords={maketitle},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{Sample Document}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello World!
% This is a comment.
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For those who want to load `hyperref` together with `accsupp`, please read [How do I prevent conflicts between accsupp and hyperref?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57151/9467).

Comment: Another note: If the rendered listing spans more than one page, copying the code might include the header and footer. It is not a requirement, but if you can avoid this, it will be better. :-)

Comment: Don't forget to compile it with `xelatex` or `pdflatex`. `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` cannot produce the expected result!!!

Comment: Note again: Compressing the PDF with `gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=%1.pdf %1-temp.pdf` will make the output no longer behave as expected.

Comment: @Werner This solution has the problem that line number references cannot be copied. See [Ulrike Fischer's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57160/9467) or the [answer of Garbage Collector](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57172/16967).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: But wasn't that the intent of the question?

Comment: @Werner The questions is about line numbers in listings. But in a reference "see line number `\ref{foobar}`" it would be odd, if the line number is omitted when copying.

Comment: It works (no copy # lines) using Adobe Reader. But using for example Sumatra (v.3.1.2 64bits) , FoxIt PhantonPDF (v.9.1.0) keep the problem (copy all, including #). PDF generated via TeXStudio (v.2.12.10).

Comment: @cbe-user-99263: Yes. PDF manipulation techniques are commonly reader-specific, and mostly work with Adobe, not always with others.

Comment: This does not work for me. I am using Adobe Acrobat online version (Outlook, Google Drive, and so on). Is it due to Adobe? How can we fix this?

Comment: @manooooh: Outlook, Google Drive, ... online? It's all viewer-dependent. It may work in the desktop reader, but can't be guaranteed for anything else.

Comment: @Werner thanks! Yes, of course online. Nowadays the people do not download documents but read them online, so I thought this answer also covered this type of viewer...

Answer (score 35):

Due to problems that came to light in the first answer when loading also the `hyperref` package, a related question was asked ([How do I prevent conflicts between accsupp and hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57151/how-do-i-prevent-conflicts-between-accsupp-and-hyperref)).
The following solution is based on [Ulrike Fischer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57160/9467) to that question, and illustrates one other advantage of this solution (as pointed out by Heiko Oberdiek) even if `hyperref` package is not involved: line numbers in references can be copied.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\usepackage{accsupp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp
\newcommand{\emptyaccsupp}[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    numberstyle=\tiny\emptyaccsupp,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\small\tt,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.54,0.13},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    morekeywords={maketitle},
    escapeinside={\%LISTING:}{\^^M},
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{Sample Document}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle %LISTING:\label{title}
Hello World!
% This is a comment.
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

Line \ref{title} shows the title.

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the listing showing selection]

I deliberately set this answer to community wiki to prevent me from getting reputation points.

Comment: In the production, I use this answer because `hyperref` can be loaded with no problem.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your CW answer to make the advantages of this solution more obvious without having to click through to the follow up question. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: This method (as well as the accepted answer) does not seem to work on Google Chrome, but it does work like a charm on Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Worth noting that while `\tiny` can be anywhere (as it takes no argument), `\emptyaccsupp` must be at the end of `\numberstyle`.

Answer (score 11):

This answer only deals with latex/dvips/ps2pdf.

Package `accsupp` works well with `dvips`. The generated PostScript file contains the right pdfmark operators. However `ghostscript` (version 9.05) has not implemented these tags, from the source file `gdevpdfm.c`:

> ```
> /* [ tag propdict /BDC pdfmark */
> static int
> pdfmark_BDC(gx_device_pdf *pdev, gs_param_string *pairs, uint count,
>             const gs_matrix *pctm, const gs_param_string *objname)
> {
>     return 0;                   /****** NOT IMPLEMENTED YET ******/
> }
>
> /* [ /EMC pdfmark */
> static int
> pdfmark_EMC(gx_device_pdf *pdev, gs_param_string *pairs, uint count,
>             const gs_matrix *pctm, const gs_param_string *objname)
> {
>     return 0;                   /****** NOT IMPLEMENTED YET ******/
> }
> ```

Solution sketch:

If the line number is not text, then it cannot be copied. Thus a solution would be to use bitmap images. For each digit and variant (color, size, …) a bitmap needs to be generated. As image format `BMP` can be used, that is supported by `dvips`. Then `\thelstnumber` is redefined to use these images for its digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative. Numbers are still typesetted as usual, but instead of typesetting it before each line is typesetted, all line numbers are typesetted after the whole code block is typesetted.

If the PDF viewer respect the "text order" in the PDF, it should work fine.

Needs 2 compilation passes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand\fakeTypesetLineNumber{m}{%
    \tikz[remember picture] \coordinate (line\the\value{lstnumber});% remember this location
    % --
    \tiny\phantom{#1}% leave space equal to the line number itself
    % \tiny must be outside any group so that it applies to the following \kern
    % --
    \xappto\typesetPendingLineNumbers{\actualTypesetLineNumber{\the\value{lstnumber}}}% remember to typeset it later
}

% this command must be robust because it's used inside \xappto
\NewDocumentCommand\actualTypesetLineNumber{m}{%
    \node [anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at (line#1){\normalfont\tiny#1};% actually typeset it now, need to copy the \tiny here
}

\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/begin}{%
    \gdef\typesetPendingLineNumbers{}%
}

\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/end}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
    \typesetPendingLineNumbers
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=1em,
    numberstyle=\fakeTypesetLineNumber,
    frame=single,
    framesep=\fboxsep,
    framerule=\fboxrule,
    rulecolor=\color{red},
    xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\small\tt,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.54,0.13},
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},
    tabsize=2,
    columns=flexible,
    morekeywords={maketitle},
    escapeinside={\%LISTING:}{\^^M},
}


\begin{lstlisting}
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \title{Sample Document}
    \author{John Smith}
    \date{\today}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle %LISTING:\label{title}
    Hello World!
    % This is a comment.
    \end{document}
\end{lstlisting}
Line \ref{title} shows the title.

\lstset{ numberstyle=\tiny }

\begin{lstlisting}
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \title{Sample Document}
    \author{John Smith}
    \date{\today}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle %LISTING:\label{title2}
    Hello World!
    % This is a comment.
    \end{document}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Of course, this will fail silently for code blocks that span across more than one page.