# How do I prevent conflicts between accsupp and hyperref?

Tags: listings, incompatibility, line-numbering

This question is related to the answer to the question [Is there a LaTeX trick to prevent a PDF viewer from copying the line number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57141/9467)

Unless you turn `hyperref` off, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\renewcommand*{\thelstnumber}{\protect\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}\arabic{lstnumber}\protect\EndAccSupp{}}

\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    numbers=left,
    columns=flexible,
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Hello\\
Universe!
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

cannot be compiled with the following error message:

[image]

How do I prevent conflicts between `accsupp` and `hyperref`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would avoid to redefine `\thelstnumber` in such a way. The command can be used in various places where such fragile content can break easily. In the case of listings I would suggest to use the key `numberstyle` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\newcommand\emptyaccsupp[1]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}}

\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    numbers=left,
    columns=flexible,
    numberstyle=\emptyaccsupp
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Hello\\
Universe!
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Then I cannot change the color and/or font of the line numbers?

Comment: You can add additional commands either to `\emptyaccsupp` or to the key: `numberstyle=\color{red}\tiny\emptyaccsupp`. (Be aware that only the last command can take an argument! The other commands must be switches).

Comment: @Forgiver: I would go with this answer. I might code some addon which adds the AccSupp code around the internal numberstyle when I find time (late next week or so).

Comment: I also think this answer is simpler than yours. I accepted this answer to finalize this topic.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Very good, because this solution also works for line number references. There the copying of line numbers should work, of course.

Answer (score 5):

It seems `hyperref` expands the `\thelstnumber` in an context which does not set `\protect` correctly (e.g. a plain `\edef`) which breaks the fragile code.
You can fix this by defining a `\theHlstnumber` which is used by `hyperref`. This macro is apparently set at the begin of the document by `hyperref` and you so you need to redefine it afterwards. Note that the original definition includes also a leading `\ifx \lst@@caption \@empty \lst@neglisting \else \thelstlisting \fi`, which you might want to add as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\renewcommand*{\thelstnumber}{\protect\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}\arabic{lstnumber}\protect\EndAccSupp{}}

\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    numbers=left,
    columns=flexible,
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\theHlstnumber}{\arabic{lstnumber}}}% or manually put it after `\begin{document}`
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Hello\\
Universe!
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am waiting for other possible answers as any hasty decision might  not be good.

Comment: @Forgiver: Absolutely no problem.

Comment: @MartinScharrer This destroys the uniqueness of `listings`' `\theHlstnumber` that adds the listings number in front of the line number.