# listings' line numbers non selectable: okay with beamer but not with (e.g.) article class (if hyperref is used)

Tags: beamer, hyperref, listings, document-classes, accsupp

The following MCE points out that it is possible to make the `listings`' line numbers non selectable (thanks to the `accsupp` package) in case of the `beamer` class.

But, in case of the standard classes (e.g. `article`) and if `hyperref` is used, the following error is thrown:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\normalfont  ...ault \seriesdefault \shapedefault 
                                                  \relax 
l.18 Foo
```

Do you know why and how to circumvent this limitation?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\DeclareRobustCommand\nonselectable[1]{%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}%
}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{%
  \nonselectable{\the\value{lstnumber}}%
}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
Foo
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57151/how-do-i-prevent-conflicts-between-accsupp-and-hyperref/57160#57160

Comment: Ooops, sorry for the duplicate. And nice solution in the linked question!