# How to exclude line numbers in code listing from being copied?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted

How to make lines code numbering uncopiable and white (or any other color)?

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: 1}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, minted, skins}

\tcbset{listing engine=minted}

\newtcblisting{javalst}{listing only, minted language=java, minted style=paraiso-dark,
    colback=bg, enhanced, frame hidden, minted options={numbersep=2.5mm, fontfamily=fdm, linenos,
    fontsize=\footnotesize, tabsize=2, breaklines, autogobble},
    overlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[bg] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=4mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
    }}

\definecolor{inline}{RGB}{187,57,82}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{22,43,58}
\setminted[java]{bgcolor=bg, fontfamily=fdm, fontsize=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{javalst}
    public class ClassName {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(args);
            }
    }
\end{javalst}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57160/38080) by @ulrike-fischer

Comment: @Rmano thank You for the comment, but unfortunately the numbering of code is still copiable, according to your link, moreover couldn't implement the code suggested by ulrike-fischer into mine properly, thanks for any help

Comment: That code is the one I use for the [circuitikz manual](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#c) --- Notice that the behavior is reader-dependent: the embedded PDF viewer in Firefox also copies the numbers but `evince` or `okular` work ok and copy just the code.

Comment: Ah, but clearly adapting it to `minted` is not trivial at all, you are right. Hmmm....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, minted, skins}

\tcbset{listing engine=minted}

\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{\texttt\footnotesize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}%<--- just add this line


\newtcblisting{javalst}{
    listing only, 
    minted language=java, 
    minted style=paraiso-dark,
    colback=bg, 
    enhanced, 
    frame hidden,
    minted options={
        fontsize=\footnotesize, 
        tabsize=2, 
        breaklines, 
        autogobble,
        linenos,
        numbersep=5pt,
        fontsize=\small,
    },
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[bg](frame.south west)rectangle([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}

}

\definecolor{inline}{RGB}{187,57,82}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{22,43,58}
\setminted[java]{bgcolor=bg, fontfamily=fdm, fontsize=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{javalst}
    public class ClassName {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(args);
            }
    }
\end{javalst}

\end{document}
```