# Error between microtype, hyperref, and listings when setting oldstylenums for listings

Tags: hyperref, listings, microtype, oldstylenums

I am using the `listings` package for displaying source code, and want to reformat the numbering to use the `oldstylenums`.
The problem comes when using `microtype`, as it throws errors for every line of code in the listing like this

```
Argument of \MT@res@a has an extra }. import
Paragraph ended before \MT@res@a was complete. import
Extra \else. import
```

- Disabling `microtype` makes LaTeX compile.
- Not reformatting the numbering makes LaTeX compile.
- Disabling `hyperref` makes LaTeX compile.

Is there a way to reformat the numbers without getting a `microtype` error, nor disabling one of the two fundamental packages `microtype` and `hyperref` for my document?

Here is my minimal, non-working example. Doing any of the above points will make it run.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

% Disabling the below makes it compile
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{upquote=true}
\lstdefinestyle{PythonStyle}{
    language=Python,
    commentstyle=\itshape,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    tabsize=4,
    numbersep=20pt, % separation between numbers and listing
    basewidth=0.5em, % the width of each character in the listing
}

% Disabling the below makes it compile
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\oldstylenums{\arabic{lstnumber}}} % nicer numbering

% Disabling the below makes it compile
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
We are at page \pageref{sec:here}.\label{sec:here}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=PythonStyle]
import numpy as np

# this is a comment

a = np.sqrt(2)
if a > 2:
    print("Interesting")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57160/2388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Ulrike Fischer for the comment above.
I thus found the working solution to be to define the number function outside the style call:

```
\newcommand\epicNumbers[1]{\oldstylenums{#1}}
```

and then calling that function inside the `lstdefinestyle` call, like this:

```
\lstdefinestyle{PythonStyle}{
    language=Python,
    ...,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,1.0}\epicNumbers,
    ...,
}
```

So the full working file is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand\epicNumbers[1]{\oldstylenums{#1}} % this line is new
\lstset{upquote=true}
\lstdefinestyle{PythonStyle}{
    language=Python,
    commentstyle=\itshape,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize\epicNumbers, % call the new number style
    tabsize=4,
    numbersep=20pt,
    basewidth=0.5em,
}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
We are at page \pageref{sec:here}.\label{sec:here}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=PythonStyle]
import numpy as np

# this is a comment

a = np.sqrt(2)
if a > 2:
    print("Interesting")
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```