# Does the trick that prevents to copy the line numbers work anymore?

Tags: listings

After updating my MiKTeX distro I have noticed that [this trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57141/is-there-a-latex-trick-to-prevent-a-pdf-viewer-from-copying-the-line-number) (the *community wiki* one) does not work anymore. I have tried to reinstall MiKTeX from scratch but the problem persists. Can someone check if it's only me?

Comment: I only have a problem if the region I'm trying to copy straddles the `listings` environment.  Otherwise it works for me.  Though, I'm not using MiKTeX; I'm working TeXLive 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the problem: seems that Adobe Reader supports this feature, Sumatra and Foxit Reader do not. And, of course I have tested the pdf only with Sumatra and Foxit...