# how to add such a footnote to the code listing

Tags: hyperref, listings, glossaries, glossaries-extra

Recently I saw a manual for working with [glossaries](https://mirror.macomnet.net/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf), [source code](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.tex) on page 14 there is a footnote with:
[image]

1. opening the source code
2. downloading it from the server
3. by downloading the finished pdf file
   I would like to implement the same in my code, please could you help me?

Approximately it should look like this:
[image]

Without the desired footnote, it looks like this:
[image]

My sources: everything is ready in [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/wykvbyfvhwyg)

#### main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{style/code-style}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{code/code.cpp}

\end{document}
```

#### style/code-style.sty

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=cyan,
}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{tabsize=12,
    breaklines,
    columns=fullflexible,
    flexiblecolumns,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle={\footnotesize},
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=true,
    }

\usepackage{longtable}



\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.4,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\def\commentstyle{\color{gray}}
\lstset{ %
  language=C++,                   % the language of the code
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
  numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{black},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line 
                                  % will be numbered
  numbersep=0.7em,                % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}, % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
  rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. commens (green here))
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  identifierstyle=\color{blue!25!black},  
  keywordstyle=\color{blue!90!black},      % keyword style
  commentstyle=\commentstyle,     % comment style
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},      % string literal style
  escapeinside={\`}{\`},          % if you want to add a comment within your code
  escapebegin=\commentstyle\footnotesize,
  %morekeywords={n,k},             % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  morecomment=[l][\color{dkgreen}]{\#}, % to color #include<cstdio> 
  morecomment=[s][\commentstyle\color{gray!50!black}]{/**}{*/}
}
```

#### code/code.cpp

```
vector<int> divisors[n + 1];
for (int a = 1; a <= n; a++)
  for (int b = a; b <= n; b += a) divisors[b].push_back(a);
```

Thank you in advance, cheers!

Comment: Just my curiosity: how will such a feature increase readability of a printed document? I‘d understand your request in the context of webpages or ebooks, which already provide many solutions.

Comment: @MS-SPO nothing ;) The idea is not to copy the code, but just download it, since when copying the code is highlighted with line numbers (I know there are (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57141/is-there-a-latex-trick-to-prevent-a-pdf-viewer-from-copying-the-line-number)) , and with the help of this footnote, you can immediately download the source code in any language, and if there is no Internet, then you can already open it on your computer apparently. Sorry for such a difficult question, I see only Nicola Talbot will help me

Answer (score 1):

Well, by the looks of it, Talbot used the `tcolorbox`, `graphicx` and `hyperref` packages to create that layout in the example you showed.

`tcolorbox` creates the box and the title with the PDF icon. The `graphicx` package is used to insert an icon into a `href` statement: `href[options]{URL}{text / icon}.

I played around a bit, downloaded a few relevant icons from the web and created this small MWE that shows the same idea's as your example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[rounded corners,arc=8pt,size=fbox,boxsep=6pt,enhanced,attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-3mm,xshift=-3mm},title={\href{url}{\includegraphics*[width=4mm]{pdf_icon.png}}}]
    \hfill \href{ulr2}{\includegraphics*[width=3mm]{clip_icon.png}}
        \hspace{1mm} \href{ulr2}{\includegraphics*[width=3mm]{down_icon.png}}
        \vspace{-18pt}
    \begin{verbatim}
        vector<int> divisors[n + 1];
        for (int a = 1; a <= n; a++)
        for (int b = a; b <= n; b += a) divisors[b].push_back(a);
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]