# Only Select Code without Line Numbers

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I'm writing a LaTeX document and want to include several listings for source code examples.

Is there a way to disable the selection of line-numbers when selecting the source code?

My prof just wants to copy/paste the source code from the final pdf-file without manually removing all the line numbers afterwards. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You can set the `listings` package to not print line numbers, but I'm not aware of how to make them "unavailable" for selection from the pdf.  Would that work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there a LaTeX trick to prevent a PDF viewer from copying the line number?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57141) and [How to make text copy in PDF previewers ignore lineno line numbers?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30783)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately I really need the line numbers. I want to reference several lines within my text.

After I kept searching, I found a solution for this problem using the following snippet:

```
\usepackage{accsupp}    
\lstset {
    numberstyle=\tiny\noncopynumber,
    columns=flexible,
}

\newcommand{\noncopynumber}[1]{
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={}}
    #1
    \EndAccSupp{}
}
```

That way the line numbers won't be selected anymore. In addition using colums=flexible I get rid of the whitespaces when copy/pasting the source code out of the pdf-file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This is pretty much the solution in the first question suggested as a duplicate ;-)