# Is it possible to get the leading spaces in copy/paste from PDF?

Tags: formatting, listings, line-numbering, clipboard

Using this solution [Only Select Code without Line Numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122256/only-select-code-without-line-numbers) I allow the listings to be copyable from PDF w/o the line numbers and many extra spaces.

But that also removes the leading spaces used for indentation!

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{SQL}
\usepackage{accsupp}    

\lstset{
     frameround=fttt
    ,language=SQL
    ,numbers=left
    ,breaklines=true
    ,showstringspaces=false
    ,basicstyle=\small
    ,numberstyle=\noncopynumber
    ,columns=flexible
}

\newcommand{\noncopynumber}[1]{
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={}}
    #1
    \EndAccSupp{}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
declare @a int

if @a = null
  select 'null' as outcome
else
  select 'not null' as outcome
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get when pasting code from PDF:

```
declare @a int
if @a = null
select ' null ' as outcome
else
select 'not null ' as outcome
if null = null
select 'equal' as outcome
else
select 'not equal' as outcome
```

There are extra spaces around `null` on line #3 and one on line #5 but all leading spaces are gone.

Comment: For the extra spaces use `columns=fullflexible`. There are no spaces in PDFs so there's nothing to copy -- see [How to copy/paste multiple spaces from lstlistings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195489/how-to-copy-paste-multiple-spaces-from-lstlistings). There's a workaround involving replacing spaces with other characters (which can be later replaced into spaces after pasting) -- see [How to make listings code indentation remain unchanged when copied from PDF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19949/how-to-make-listings-code-indentation-remain-unchanged-when-copied-from-pdf).

Comment: That messes up the listings by making them essentially non-column-alignable. There has to be another solution.