# uncopyable watermark

Tags: watermark

is it possible to get watermark text, which is not copyable in PDF? it bothers when doing proofreadings. I mean something like uncopyable line numbers [How to make text copy in PDF previewers ignore lineno line numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30783/how-to-make-text-copy-in-pdf-previewers-ignore-lineno-line-numbers)

here is a minimum example

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{czech}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}\SetWatermarkText{blabla}

\begin{document}

ddd

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want the watermark to be locked or the text beneath it?

Comment: the watermark (blabla), not the text

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe the `accsupp` package, which allows the watermark to appear on the page, but the "ActualText" internal to the pdf to be different (in this case, removed).

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%    \setmainlanguage{czech}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}\SetWatermarkText{%
\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={}}blahbla\EndAccSupp{}
}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\begin{document}
ddd
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need, thank you very much!

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Can you please explain your answer a little bit more. I don't understand it. What does the `\BeginAccSupp` realy does? And why is the `accsupp` package loaded after and not before?

Comment: @buhtz A PDF file has (potentially) several "layers" of data.  The outward is the visual image, which , in and of itself, carries no copy/pastable information.  The primary sublayer, if it exists, contains the information about what letters/words occur on the page and in which location.  It is this layer that responds to the click and copy command.  The`accsupp` package allows one to deliberately place different information on the visual PDF layer from the copy sublayer.  In the visual layer, `blahbla` is the watermark; in the copy layer, nothing `{}` comprises the watermark.