# Is there a way to make the page numbering nonselectable

Tags: pdf, page-numbering, copy-paste

Is there any way in pdflatex to make the page numbers non selectable in the outputed documents. I know that there are some pdfs floating around out there where the page number is not included in selects. By page numbers I mean the ones placed at the bottom of each page to mark the current page, not those placed by using a reference command.

Comment: Which page numbers do you mean? In the ToC/LoF/LoT/ListOfWhatever? In a page reference by `\pageref` or in `\cite` - generated references?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Updated question to be more clear. I mean the page numbers that mark the page as being that page.

Comment: Related: [How to make text copy in PDF previewers ignore `lineno` line numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30783/5764)

Comment: Would it be enough if the pagenumbers would not be included if the selected text is copied?

Answer (score 6):

The following is reader-specific:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,accsupp,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyfoot[C]{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}\thepage\EndAccSupp{}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

[`accsupp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) provides the ability to set content in the document, but let the rendered PDF have it think it's something else.

As mentioned, it's reader-specific. Here's the same selection-view within SumatraPDF:

[image]

Note how the page number (1) is selected.