# Attach listing to PDF

Tags: listings, pdf, embedding

I would like to add listings source as attachment to a PDF (created by `pdflatex`). For `\lstinputlisting` this is pretty easy:

```
\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{embedfile}

\let\lstinputlistingO=\lstinputlisting
\renewcommand{\lstinputlisting}[2][]{\embedfile{\detokenize{#2}}\lstinputlistingO[#1]{#2}}
```

but how can I do the same with `\begin{listing} ... \end{listing}`?  (referenced filename should be the something like `listing 12`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [`embedfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) can only embed external files, you [have to write the content of the environment to a file first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37795/3323). To do this, the capabilities of the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package, namely the `\lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile` macro, can be used:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{embedfile}

\makeatletter
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}

\lstnewenvironment{lstembedlisting}[2][]{%
\bgroup%
\lstset{#1}%
\lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{#2}%
}
{%
\lst@EndWriteFile%
\embedfile{#2}%
\egroup%
}
\makeatother
```

This code snippet creates a new environment called `lstembedlisting`, which can be used like the normal `lstlisting`, except that it expects an additional filename as a mandatory argument. The code inside the environment is typeset and written to that file at the same time. Afterwards, `\embedfile` is called to attach it to the PDF.

#### Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{embedfile}

\makeatletter
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}

\lstnewenvironment{lstembedlisting}[2][]{%
\bgroup%
\lstset{#1}%
\lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{#2}%
}
{%
\lst@EndWriteFile%
\embedfile{#2}%
\egroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstembedlisting}[language=TeX]{listing_12.tex}
Hello world!
\bye
\end{lstembedlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since it is tricky working with `verbatim` content, which is the case when dealing with [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings), there is no easy single-command way out in my opinion. A two-step process using the [`filecontents` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents), however, is easy. Not as clean as diabonas' answer though...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{embedfile}% http://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents

% Automatically embed listings file as attachment with \lstinputlisting
\let\lstinputlistingO=\lstinputlisting
\renewcommand{\lstinputlisting}[2][]{\embedfile{\detokenize{#2}}\lstinputlistingO[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{A.tex} % Insert listing and embed in PDF

% Write listing to file
\begin{filecontents*}{B.tex}
Here is some more code
\end{filecontents*}
\lstinputlisting{B.tex} % Insert listing and embed in PDF
\end{document}
```

`filecontents` allows for using the `filecontents` (and `filecontents*`) environment outside the preamble of your document. If you don't like using `filecontents*` and would rather use something like `\begin{listing}`...`\end{listing}`, you could add the following to your document preamble:

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\listing\csname filecontents*\endcsname
\expandafter\let\expandafter\endlisting\csname endfilecontents*\endcsname
```

However, adapting `filecontents` in general to accept an optional argument (which would include your listing formatting) is rather difficult, apart from rewriting the package (as far as I know).

This option saves the file first and then inputs it. The opposite approach of setting it first and then embedding it would be more difficult.