# Minted: how to make it so that linenos cannot be highlighted with the cursor?

Tags: minted, accsupp

For example, if you had

```
\begin{minted}[linenos]{cpp}
    map<string, int> m;
    m["FT"]=4;
    m["EK"]=6;
\end{minted}
```

how could you make it so that when you highlight the code in the PDF, the line numbers do not get highlighted?

I've tried things like redefining `\theFancyVerbLine` using the `accsupp` package, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I see you have tried [copy paste - How can I make source code included with minted copyable? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83204/how-can-i-make-source-code-included-with-minted-copyable). Unfortunately your PDF viewer does not support accsupp properly, so not much can be done. (see the last comment below the answer)

Comment: I added an answer to the linked question containing an approach without `accsup`.