# Click to copy code snippets to clipboard in Latex-generated PDF

Tags: code

The [Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) has a wonderful feature where you can click an icon for the source code examples and it will copy it to the clipboard.

Can this functionality be emulated in a LaTeX-generated PDF?

Bonus question: A few of the example snippets elide the `main` along with other uninteresting scaffolding for a particular example; see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-01-vectors.html). But when you click the copy button, the scaffolding and the main are present on the clipboard. Can this be emulated in a LaTex-generated PDF?

Comment: As far as I know: No.

Comment: The first part: probably yes although it might be viewer-dependent (read: for Adobe). The second part will be hard as this piece of information is not contained in the PDF, so you would have to use an attachfile/embedfile solution.

Comment: Maybe you can check ou this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174637/copy-to-clipboard-feature-in-pdf-output