# Copy linked text to clipboard in PDF output

Tags: copy-paste, clipboard

How can I realize the following:
Click on a linked text in my PDF file. This copies the linked text to my clipboard and I can then copy the text into an email etc.

Comment: This question might be interesting for you: [Copy to clipboard feature in PDF output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545107/204085)