# Is it possible to not copy numeration using lstlisting?

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, lstlisting

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset {%
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=2,
    %columns=fullflexible,
    keepspaces=true,
    language=C++,
    columns=flexible,
    %numberstyle=\noncopynumber                             % 1. If this line is only uncommented it produces 6 errors
    %numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray}                      % 2. If this line is only uncommented it compiles
    %numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray}\noncopynumber        % 3. If this line is only uncommented it produces 6 errors
}

%\newcommand{\noncopynumber}[1]{%                           % Answer
    %\BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={}}%
    %#1%
    %\EndAccSupp{}%
%}

%\makeatletter                                              % Answer
%\def\lst@outputspace{{\ifx\lst@bkgcolor\empty\color{white}\else\lst@bkgcolor\fi\lst@visiblespace}}
%\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Example code line 1
*
... and 3
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it using `LaTeX->PS->PDF` the output is very fancy:

[image: Original output]

However, when I am going to copy the text and paste it into a compiler (or anywhere else):

[image: Bad copy]

I tried the [Martin Scharrer solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30310/152550) with differents options:

1. (Martin Scharrer solution) [image: Example 1]
2. (added by me) [image: Example 2]
3. (suggested by [TeXnician answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442600/152550)) [image: Example 3]

As you can see the problem is that **the reference numbers (`1`, `2` and `3`) are copied** from PDF to any text editor even with the proposed solution.

I also take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19978/152550), [here](http://tex.bootmath.com/how-to-make-listings-code-correct-copyable-from-pdf-and-with-hyperlink.html) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/QOyv2EgwGSY) but it does not work for me too (by the way please check that solutions).

I have code around all the full document.

Is there any easy solution to this problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** [TeXnician's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442600/152550) works for me as long as I keep the `PDF` file on my computer **without sharing it via the Internet**. However, when I try to upload it to, for example, Outlook his solution is without effect. You can see the reproduction in [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEhbk.jpg) *(use fullscreen mode to see better the selected text in both `PDF`)*.

**EDIT 2: also tested the Werner solution in *[Is there a LaTeX trick to prevent a PDF viewer from copying the line number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57141/152550)* (adding `\protect` command inside the new command of TeXnician and/or renewing the `\thelstnumber` command) with the same results.**

Comment: Off-topic: you really ought not use `vmargin`.

Comment: "Use `geometry` instead" `:)`. I remember that @cfr, but if I change it to `geometry` then the `\setpapersize{A4},\setmargins{2.2cm},...` code produces 3 errors. How would you fix that?

Comment: Obviously, you have to use `geometry`'s facilities. I would add `a4paper` as a class option and then use `\geometry{margin=2.2cm,...}` with whatever other options you need. (I don't know what all those arguments are for. `texdoc geometry` for a full list of options.

Comment: @cfr I will try. Btw I think if you propose that change you have to give me (or to anyone) the correct code for testing and then adopt the new package..

Comment: I think that's a ridiculous claim. First, I clearly don't *have* to do it. Second, I don't think I'm under any particular obligation to do it. If your claim were true, it would mean that every time somebody points out that the template somebody is using is crap, they're obligated to provide alternative code for the person's entire thesis format. The point is, I'd have to learn `vmargin` to give you equivalent code. That's a waste of my time because I shouldn't use the package. Whereas your learning `geometry` isn't a waste of your time, because you should use that package.

Comment: For the purposes of the question this is *off-topic*. Then, I accept your suggestion in order to see some changes... As I don't see changes why I would change my structure of code if, for **my purposes**, using `vmargin` or `geometry` is exactly the same? I really appreciate your suggestion, really, I trust you, but I am here not to fix that issue, but to fix these two problems that I posted with your help. When I find the solution that you gave me I will take a look at `geometry`.

Comment: Do you see my point of view, @cfr? Please, tell me if using `geometry` is really necessary and I will take a look now. I do not like to disobey you because I know that you all know much more than me...

Comment: May I add that your MWE is not minimal? You do not even need the page setup stuff here.

Comment: It's not necessary to use `geometry`. @cfr pointed out a *recommendation*. You can follow this *advice* or not. If there's a wasp nest, some people would recommend you to leave it alone. You can do with your code whatever you want (as long as no one cooperates, at least). You can rape it, make it entirely unreadable, format in-line... But I'd rather not *recommend* this. You shouldn't *request* something, nor get as cocky as to tell advisers they have to implement stuff in **your** code. We're in userland, users help users, you don't employ the users. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17447

Comment: @cfr I removed the `vmargin` package `;)`. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have one obvious problem in your code: You set `numberstyle` to make it non-copyable and then you reset it with fancy font stuff. Any option is overwritten at a later use. The effects do not add up. So you need that one line: `numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray}\noncopynumber`.

A true MWE showing how to apply your macro would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand{\noncopynumber}[1]{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={}}%
    #1%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
}

\lstset {%
    numbers = left,%
    numberstyle=\tiny\noncopynumber
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Example code line 1
*
... and 3
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Concerning your problem with the asterisk I don't know what you literate, but using the proper unicode code point with `{*}{{\char"002A}}1` (or alternatively `\**`) gives the correct char which can be copied as you would expect it to be copied.

Comment: Your first solution does not to work for me. I have upgrade my question for more readable, and I have removed the question about bad asterisks because I have found an answer before.

Comment: @manooooh Why don't you include the `accsupp` package which is obviously required?

Comment: @manooooh See my updated answer.

Comment: I regret having canceled your answer but if I compile your code (adding `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`) and open the PDF Outlook then numbers are copied too (but not in Acrobat Reader for Windows 10). Please see [this image](https://imgur.com/a/QWca4SS).

Comment: @manooooh I'm on Linux and for me it works even with Spanish babel. I use a fully updated TL2018. Unfortunately I can't reproduce your problem, so I can't adapt my answer.

Comment: Oh `:(`. Did you try sending the file via email? I could reproduce it [in this gif](https://imgur.com/YGDdlc0). Please take a look and try to tell how to fix that when uploading the `PDF` file to Internet with this example.

Comment: @manooooh That has nothing to do with email, but rather with the used viewer. I don't quite get the mechanics of PDF, but probably the viewer (is it pdf.js?) doesn't correctly interpret what is in the pdf stream.

Comment: I know, I just make an example. I use the free Acrobat Reader DC for Windows 10. I do not know which viewer has the email. However, it still does not work. If you need more information please let me know.