# How to remove indent characters when copying from PDF document using listings package

Tags: spacing, listings, copy-paste

I am pretty sure I read something about this before, but I can not find it. Mark it as a duplicate if so please.

I am coding inside `lstlisting` environment using SPACEBAR for separate words and TAB for indent code. Check this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\newcommand\opstyle{\bfseries\color{red}}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{xcolor,textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstset { %
    language=C++,
    alsoletter=0123456789,
    upquote=true,
    columns=fullflexible,
    keepspaces=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},
  breakatwhitespace=false,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  keepspaces=true,            
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                  
  tabsize=2
}

\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}{\ProcessOther@silmeth}

\newcommand\ProcessOther@silmeth
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%     % If we're in `Processing' mode...
    \def\lst@thestyle{\opstyle}%  % ... redefine the style locally
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

%========================== Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442600/152550
\newcommand{\noncopynumber}[1]{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={}}%
    #1%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
}

\makeatletter   %================= Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19978/152550
\def\lst@outputspace{{\ifx\lst@bkgcolor\empty\color{white}\else\lst@bkgcolor\fi\lst@visiblespace}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Example with no tabulation

    With one tabulation

 With one space
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The output with selected text:

[image: Example]

**When I paste it anywhere, it turns on the spaces:**

[image: Spaces]

This way a compiler could never compile correctly.

Is there an easy way to **keep spacing but no with this symbol: `␣`**?

Thanks!

*P.D*: I also take a look at the [manual](http://www.pvv.ntnu.no/~berland/latex/docs/listings.pdf), section 2.5 *Special characters* - *Visible tabulators and spaces* but it does not say anything about this problem. Also I take a look at section 7, *How tos* - *How to gobble characters*.

Comment: [Your commented link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19978/164314) explicitly said “[t]his hack is not perfect, however, as the typesetted character is really a visible space, not a space (so searching the pdf for `char line` will not work) and some PDF readers (like Mac's preview) will copy a visible space. It works under Acrobat Reader and it's extremely pleasant to be able to quickly copy/paste code without problem”. Also, on another note, please use `basicstyle=\ttfamily` to display source code.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I follow the suggestion of [koleygr comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19949/how-to-make-listings-code-indentation-remain-unchanged-when-copied-from-pdf/19978#comment935841_19978) in the same link and it works partially; although it eliminates that character, the indentation does not hold. Do you want to post an answer referring to him to solve partially this question?

Comment: I’m happy to help! I merely quoted from @PhilippeGoutet. If you think you’ve found a satisfactory solution, you’re more than welcome to answer yourself. In fact, it is [*explicitly encouraged* to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). :)