# How to insert copyable code in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, python

I want to add Python code into my document, but the common solution (/lstlisting) generates text with spaces between each letter, messes up indentation, and doesn't include line breaks, which are crucial since I want to be able to copy the code from my document after I'm done.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See the discussion here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563803/how-make-a-latex-document-that-generates-a-pdf-from-which-copy-paste-works-corre](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563803/how-make-a-latex-document-that-generates-a-pdf-from-which-copy-paste-works-corre)

Comment: Ususally the `minted` package preserves the code a bit better when copied as compared to `listings` considering spaces and line breaks, although indentation is still problematic (but a good programming editor can re-indent the code automatically).