# Hiding extra string space in pdf document by using latex - overleaf

Tags: code

I am trying to type Python code by using LaTeX. The code is not being formatted properly

Example:

```
#PDF
var = function(data, parameter= 'compile') 


#Copy it on my terminal
var = function(data, parameter= ' compile ')
```

Does someone has some suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: I'd recommend using a code-listing environment so that the python code is not interpreted as 'normal' text. Some suggestions and options for this are provided here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_listing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I forgot to mention that I am using it. I am using the listings library. However, everytime that I am trying to copy my code from the compiled pdf, there are hiding extra space in the strings when I paste it on my terminal.

Comment: It can happen with some listing settings, flexible columns work better, but generally copy &paste pf code from pdf is not reliable.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice! Yes, I know that copy and paste from pdf is not reliable, but someone might use it when trying to use the code. Your suggestion worked. I just added \begin{lstlisting}[columns=flexible,language=python], and the hiding spaces disapered. Many thanks!

Comment: (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563803/how-make-a-latex-document-that-generates-a-pdf-from-which-copy-paste-works-corre for other links)