# How to print spaces and tabs as spaces and tabs in 'lstlisting's?

Tags: listings, white-space

Consider the following:

---

```
\begin{lstlisting}
int main(void)
{
  printf("hello world");
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

---

[image]

*[Note: the text is not actually rendered blue, I just tried to select it in the PDF --- end note]*

---

Does anyone know how to keep the tabs & whitespaces as tabs & whitespaces ? So that when trying to select the listing in the PDF, it selects the tabs and spaces and I can copy paste it without having to re-tab and re-space everything in my editor ?

Also not replace the spaces and tabs with that weird looking underscore spaces and tab pretender character. Just replace it with actual space and tab or even just space would be fine?

Comment: "So that when trying to select the listing in the PDF, it selects the tabs and spaces and I can copy paste it without having to re-tab and re-space everything in my editor?" This is not supported by PDF format. You can, however, embed the code snippet into PDF, see packages like [`embedfile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile).

Comment: [How to make listings code indentation remain unchanged when copied from PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19949/134144) might be helpful.