# Problems with copy and paste from PDF using lstlisting (Again)

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, extended-characters

So I had already posted a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51604) concerning the minus sign (`-`), but now I have an issue with the apostrophe (`'`) that the previous solutions do not seem to solve. This seems to be a problem unrelated to `listings` since I cannot even get `\verb!'!` to create a PDF that when copied I get ASCII code 39. All I manage to get is an extended character (e2 80 99 according to hexdump).

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\verb!'!
\end{document}
```

So the question is:

> How can I create a PDF that shows a single quote that when copied has the ASCII value of a single quote?

Comment: With `pdflatex` I get a quote. What engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using pdflatex. Are you sure? It looks like a quote...but did you copy and paste it?

Comment: After copying, emacs says `character: ' (39, #o47, #x27)` which is `name: APOSTROPHE`.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Here, after copying, emacs said `’ (8217, #o20031, #x2019)` which is `name: RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`

Answer (score 8):

In the absence of a ToUnicode CMap pdf viewers will do some heuristics to try to map the glyphs to unicode code points, but beyond ASCII this can be flakey and work only some of the time in some viewers. (See for example [this patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US20060288281)). Hence Stephan Lehmke seeing different results to Yossi Farjoun. You can add a tounicode table easily enough, but the character in question is a `quoteright` which usually maps to `U+2019`. You could make the mapping for `quoteright` to `U+0027` (the code point for the `quotesingle` glyph) which will solve your immediate problem but then single-right quotes elsewhere in the document (outside listings) would be affected. I found there is an undocumented "namespace" feature of `\pdfglyphtounicode` that allows to restrict the remapping to typewriter fonts only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input glyphtounicode.tex
\input glyphtounicode-cmr.tex
\pdfglyphtounicode{tfm:cmtt10/quoteright}{0027}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}
\verb!'! `hello'
\end{document}
```

Actually, it turns out that cmtt10 does in fact contain a `quotesingle` glyph which you may prefer to use anyway (in which case the `\pdfglyphtounicode` line above is not needed). To access this glyph use `\usepackage{textcomp}` and then `\texttt{\textquotesingle}` should do it. For the listings environment I believe you can do `\lstset{upquote=true}` to make it use this glyph when it sees an ASCII apostrophe.

Comment: Great answer! A lot of useful information in there! :-)

Answer (score 1):

With [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings), you can use the `upquote=true` option combined with `\usepackage{textcomp}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\lstset{upquote=true}

\begin{document}
\lstinline!'!
\end{document}
```