Not sure how to get more delimeters in tcblistings environment
I am trying to define a style for metavariables in code. My WE is below...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


% define colors for code blocks
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{codebackcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{EfD}{HTML}{f7f7f7}
\definecolor{EFD}{HTML}{28292e}

% use listings for code block styling
\usepackage{listings}
\lstalias{hdl}{}

% line numbers and white space
\usepackage[space=true]{accsupp}

% create non-copy numbers (source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57160)
\newcommand{\copyablespace}{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=00A0}\hphantom{x}\EndAccSupp{}}

% copy-able whitespace (source - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142765)
\newcommand\donotcopy[1]{% line number printing mechanism
  \BeginAccSupp{ActualText={}}#1\EndAccSupp{}%
}

\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

% make all lstnumbers two-digit
\renewcommand{\thelstnumber}{%
  \ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\arabic{lstnumber}%
}

% define the code snippet style
\lstdefinestyle{code}{
  numbers=left, 
  numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{black!40!white}\donotcopy, 
  captionpos=t,
  abovecaptionskip=0pt,
  belowcaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  xleftmargin=0.5em,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\selectfont,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{pblue},
  stringstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
  commentstyle=\bfseries\color{black!60},
  showspaces=false,
  tabsize=2,
  extendedchars=true,
  morekeywords={*,...},            % if more keywords should be added to the set
  alsoletter={()[].=},
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keepspaces=true,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  escapeinside={!>}{<!},
  tabsize=1,
  emphstyle={\bfseries\color{pblue}},
  columns=fullflexible,
  literate={0}{0}{1}%
  {1}{1}{1}%
  {2}{2}{1}%
  {3}{3}{1}%
  {4}{4}{1}%
  {5}{5}{1}%
  {6}{6}{1}%
  {7}{7}{1}%
  {8}{8}{1}%
  {9}{9}{1}%
  {\ }{{\copyablespace}}1
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1,
}

\newtcblisting[auto counter]{tcblstcode}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  top=\smallskipamount,
  bottom=2.5\smallskipamount,
  sharp corners=downhill,
  arc=0.5cm,
  colback=EfD!98!EFD,
  colframe=EfD!95!EFD,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    xshift=-2mm
  },
  boxed title style={
    size=small,
    colback=white,
    colframe=white,
    boxrule=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    left=0pt
  },
  fonttitle=\color{black},
  listing only,
  listing options={
    style=code,
    moredelim={**[is][\color{green}]{@}{@}},
    #1
    % numbers=\ifpgfkeysvalueof{/codeFormattingKeys/showlines}=1 left\else none\fi
  },
  /codeFormattingKeys/.cd,#1,/tcb/.cd
}

\pgfkeys{
  /codeFormattingKeys/caption/.style    = {/tcb/title={\ifx #1\empty\empty\else\ \textbf{Code Snippet~\thetcbcounter.} #1\fi}},
  /codeFormattingKeys/language/.style = {/tcb/listing options app={language=#1}},
  /codeFormattingKeys/src/.style  = {
    /tcb/overlay={
      \begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \fill[gray!25](frame.south west)
        rectangle ([xshift=5.0mm]frame.north west);
      \end{tcbclipinterior}
      \node[inner sep=0.75mm,rounded corners=0.5mm,anchor=north east,fill=gray!50] at ([xshift=-2.5mm, yshift=\baselineskip + 1mm]frame.south east){\scriptsize\color{violet}\itshape\ttfamily#1};
    },
  },
  % /codeFormattingKeys/showlines/.initial = 1 % Default is 1 (show lines), 
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcblstcode}[language=python]
    print("Hello World") @hello@
\end{tcblstcode}
\end{document}

I end up with...

when instead I expect the 'hello' surrounded by '@'s to be colored green. What can be done to fix this?
Update - It seems like this is an issue of defining moredelims for all languages, since the desired behavior occurs when no language is set. Is it possible to set moredelims for more than one language?
