# Remove spaces inside quote in Listings

Tags: spacing, listings, quotation

I'm using TexMaker with PDFLatex.
My problem is that the code lines in the listing

```
    ress := 'articles';
    test := 'something';
    test := 'somethingarticles';
    test := 'arrtticclleess';
```

are showed as

```
    ress := ' articles ';
    test := 'something';
    test := 'somethingarticles';
    test := ' arrtticclleess ';
```

in the pdf file. For defining the listings I use this code:

```
\lstset{
    literate=%
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {~}{{\textasciitilde}}1,
    float=hbp,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier},
    keywordstyle=\color{colKeys},
    stringstyle=\color{colString},
    commentstyle=\color{colComments},
    backgroundcolor=\color{hellgelb},
    columns=flexible,
    tabsize=2,
    frame=single,
    extendedchars=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    breaklines=true,
    breakautoindent=true,
    captionpos=b,
}
\lstdefinelanguage{al}{
    sensitive=true,
    upquote=true,
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, 
    morestring=[b]',
    alsodigit={-,*},
    morekeywords={
        local,var,procedure,temporary,begin,end,exit,if,else,then,repeat,
        until,case,of}
}
```

How can this inconsistent behaviour happen?? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phantom spaces in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4911/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the related feature from stackexchange. I found the answer here:

[Phantom spaces in listings (pdf)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4911/phantom-spaces-in-listings-pdf?rq=1)

I had to change the following line in the \lstset{

```
columns=flexible,
```

to

```
columns=fullflexible,
```

to get the spaces away. But what I still don't understand is the different behaviour before (sometimes spaces, sometimes not). Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Good! I added the related question to your question ("Close" because it's a duplicate). Next time, better provide a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).