# Copy code from lstlisting excluding line number

Tags: listings, copy-paste

I have this latex code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}  % Environment meant for source code (useful for word-wrapping verbatim text)

\begin{document}
\lstset{basicstyle = \verbatim@font,columns=fullflexible,numbers=left}
    
\begin{lstlisting}
//Define Variables
Test1_up = [XZ:This (Index)][1];
Test2_down = [XZ:This Index][1];
        
//Specify Parameter Values
beta1 = .2238202445016966;
beta2 = .6676275732948469;
\end{lstlisting}
    
\end{document}
```

It shows:

[image]

And when the reader try to select the code to copy/paste it, the line numbers are also selected:

[image]

Does exists some latex feature that let the reader copy the code excluding the line numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57141/is-there-a-latex-trick-to-prevent-a-pdf-viewer-from-copying-the-line-number (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57151/how-do-i-prevent-conflicts-between-accsupp-and-hyperref).  Notice however that if it works or not depends a lot on the viewer. `pdf.js` (the embedded viewer in most browser) is normally quite bad at it.

Comment: You can check it with https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf --- in the browser, the line numbers are copied. But if you download it, for example in `evince`, you just copy the code. I do not think there is a solution to this...

Comment: A solution could be that the numbers not typeset as letters but as PS paths. But I don't even know whether there exists a package for that ...

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4911/phantom-spaces-in-listings. In general, copy&paste from PDF is always a nightmare (especially if the language is sensitive to spaces --- Python is especially bad for that).